# How do I count multiple lines in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a very new Python user. My project is to take a very long (20k lines) file that includes movies and actors in them and refine it. I'm trying to find out which of the movies listed has the highest number of actors.

I'm not sure how to do multiple counts of a single file.

This is the file that starts the project. It repeats like that with different movie titles for 20k lines. [Pic of original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBZEg.png) The first part of the project is to build a list which contains every movie's full cast list which is what the code below does. Now what I'm trying to do is get the program to count how many actors is in each movie and print which one has the highest number of actors.

```
    lines_seen = list()
    fhand = open...
    #opens but I don't want to show address


    actors = list()
    titles = list()

    is_Actor = True

    for line in fhand:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if (is_Actor):
            titles.append(line)
            if line not in lines_seen:
                lines_seen.append("The title of the movie is:")
                lines_seen.append(line)
                print(" ")
                print("The title of the movie is '", line, "'")
                print("The actors in the movie are:")
        elif not (is_Actor):
            lines_seen.append(line)
            print(line)
            actors.append(line)
        is_Actor = not(is_Actor)

    fhand.close()
```

Heres what I've done so far

```
actors = dict()

is_Title = True

for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    if (is_Title):
        if line not in actors:
            actors[line] = 1
        else:
            actors[line] = actors[line] + 1
    is_Title = not is_Title
```

Now I'm trying to get it to return the highest value. I've googled it and it tells me to use max() but that returns a value of 97 when I know the highest value is 207. What do I do from here?

Comment: It helps to have fully contained and running examples. You could show an example of a dozen lines, open it as "test.txt" and show processing from there. Also try for a more complete description of the input. It looks like every other line is the name of a movie and one actor in the movie. Is that correct?

Comment: What is the `words = line.split()` line doing? I don't see it being used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation #1:  Make yourself a small chunk of data that you can experiment with and read/print results.  It will be 55x (my estimate) easier to troubleshoot than 20k lines.  Maybe 2 movies, 1 with 2 actors, 1 with 1 actor.

Are you familiar with python dictionaries?  It seems what you want to do is associate a list of actors with a movie title.  Then you can inspect the sizes of the lists in the dictionary to find the one with the highest length.

In basic Python, you should ...

- make an empty dictionary outside of your loop to hold the results, as you are doing with actors, etc.
- start reading the file.  It seems like your data is in a predictable pattern that the title is followed by a single actor name, so if you want to keep your current reading construct (an alternate would be to read 2 lines each pass through a different loop) you need to "hold onto the movie title" until the next loop to get the actor, so in pseudocode you could modify your loop to something like:

---

```
title = None
is_actor = False  
for line in fhand:
    if not is_actor:  # you have a title...
        title = line
    else:             # you have an actor
        # get the list from the dictionary for the current title, or make a new list if no entry yet
        # add the actor to the list
        # put the list back into the dictionary
    is_actor = not is_actor
```

- Then inspect your dictionary and manipulate it as needed

For a primer on dictionaries (and other introductory concepts) I strongly recommend [Think Python](https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html).  See the whole chapter on dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I posted what I've got but I've run into another problem